# Would VR sex work?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, virtual-reality

I just don't know if it's feasible. Say there is a girl I like that would never look twice at me. Then let's say with advanced virtual reality technology, I am able to recreate a simulation of her.

- Would it be realistic?
- Could it actually convince me that I'm having sex with that person?
- How would it work?

I asked a similar question about haptic holograms and I was told that they wouldn't work (you can't have sex with a hologram). They mentioned that Claytronics or programmable matter would be the only way to create this fantasy.

Anyway, will VR sex in reality probably be like using an Oculus Rift or could we create Matrix-style simulated realities?

Comment: That's a *lot* of questions-

Comment: learn to lucid dream

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Max*! Those are a lot of questions and we have a policy of only allowing one question per post to make it easier to search for an answer if you are having a question. Could you please [edit] your post to focus on the question that you are most interested in right now? You can always ask the other questions at a later time and refer to the existing questions by linking them. Also you mention that you already asked a similar question. Could you link it? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about how the site works. Have fun!

Comment: @Max You mentioned "haptic" in the question, have you ever had any experience with haptics systems?  Our college had a haptics lab, which could recreate the feeling of interacting with real world objects though the use of a stylus. It felt like you were pushing on a real rubber ball, and when you slid the pen along the surface you could feel it skip due to the friction. This is all achieved with robotics, and very refined actuators as well as programming to produce the correct effects. There are simulations for skin and organs for surgical simulations...  so yes.

Comment: It would requires a full body haptics suit and be modified for such purpose but the technology already exists, I'm not aware of anyone using it for such... but it certainly could be done. I've imagined the applications for immersive first person shooters.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it would work. Not necessarily because it would convince you, but because you would convince yourself. The more realistic the VR is (and it is getting better all the time), the easier it will be for you to believe, but you start off wanting to believe and so you automatically set a lower threshold, and the more you want to believe, the lower that threshold is.

It is likely that, because you are satisfying your own wishes, and because the VR is also trying to do so, it will actually be more convincing than real life, because it will be more satisfying. That in itself might be dangerous.

Comment: :-) simultaneous same idea.

Comment: @Amadeus yes, seemed obvious enough to me :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would work. Sexual excitement in particular shuts down various analytic parts of the brain, making it easier.

There is nothing in theory that prevents us from creating realistic robotics and prosthetic sexual organs that would seem real enough to feel like the real thing; *since you don't know what that partner would actually feel like.*

In other words, it is possible to make it feel like you were having intercourse with a real person; and the robot can be programmed to physically respond like a real person.

That is mostly muscular action that isn't nearly as hard to emulate as expressions, vocals, eye movement, etc. We can do much of that with the motion dots you see being used when they translate a human actor's movements into a cartoon's movements. Similar recordings could be used to capture a library of copulation movements; and the robot could select to replay what seems appropriate for its physical situation.

Programmers would have far more trouble with the face, mouth, eyes, vocal tract, jaw, etc. Although we can capture motion; the actual mechanics of expression and voice are much more difficult to emulate.

As for whether it could convince you: Of course not, you know its a robot! But perhaps you can convince yourself that you had experienced what it would really be ***like*** to have sex with that person, within some margin of error, which might be enough to stop the obsession.

Answer (score 1):

**For sex's primary purpose?**

No, unless you had some kind of high speed fluid transport system.

**For sex's other purpose?**

Maybe.  If you could include sensations beyond just the sight and sound of current systems then yes.  If not, then it is just another form of porn and that would work for any individual as well as the standard kind does.