# What's a good sci-fi word or phrase to name a generic copy of the SQUID?

Tags: technology, virtual-reality

I'm very interested in the SQUID from the sci fi movie Strange Days. For those who don't know, the SQUID is a headset thing that allows the wearer to record what was happening to him/her directly from the cerebral cortex and then experienced afterward by another person. It's essentially virtual reality but I'm very interested in it for my sci fi world but I don't wanna rip off Strange Days. What's a good generic type sci-fi-like name for this kind of technology? I'm asking basically for taking a V8 but just calling it vegetable juice.

Comment: Name questions like this are not a good fit for StackExchange.  They're always too opinion based to fit their Q&A format.

Comment: I see that you are unregistered and [asked a question before](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88663/would-vr-sex-work). If you would like to merge your accounts please follow [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233/352819). Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how the site works. This question is very opinion-based and might therefore get closed. We don't know what contributes a "good word" for you and this site is dedicated to giving objectively correct answers, not brainstorm ideas for you. Have fun on the site!